# CAN socket - handle not ACK

Tags: can-bus, socketcan, python-can

I'm trying to test getting the ACK bit from a CAN network. My system has an RPI 4, PICAN DUO and transceivers to other CAN nodes. When the RPI and the other node are both connected, all is well and I'm getting 2 way communication.

When the RPI is by itself, I'm sending a Message and should receive an Error, indicating no ack has occurred, but I'm getting nothing.

Configuration:

`can.interface.Bus(interface="socketcan", receive_own_messages=True, channel="can1", bitrate=500000, err_reporting=True)`

Comment: Make sure you aren't in some "loop back" test mode.

Comment: To clarify - Is there a way to get an error/status from python-can after sending a message to a working socketCAN bus without any nodes connected (hence no CAN ACK)?

Answer (score 0):

You do not deal directly with **ACK**, but you can be notified when such event happens. All relevant info can be found in [Linux SocketCAN documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/can.html).

If you want implementation details, at [this link](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,39858.msg403874.html#msg403874) you can find my **hlcanerrdump** tool which can parse and show all errors on CAN bus (including **NoAck**), and **hlcanerrsim** tool for simulating all kinds of CAN bus errors. Study the source code and you will understand how to achieve what you want.